# getting data from jcombo box and converting it to float

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

This is my jComboBox:

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "3", "4" }));

   jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
```

I want to get the value selected that is `3` or `4` and convert it into `float`?

This is what I have tried:

```
a = Float.parseFloat(jComboBox1.getActionCommand());
```

but it doesn't seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get selected object([`getSelectedItem()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedItem%28%29) method) and convert it to `Float` like next:

```
Object o = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
Float floatValue = Float.valueOf(o.toString());
System.out.println(floatValue);
```

or at runtime you need to use `ItemListener` :

```
jComboBox1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                Object o = event.getItem();
                Float floatValue = Float.valueOf(o.toString());
                System.out.println(floatValue);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: let me try it @alex2410

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with the value out of the `JComboBox`, not the action Command.  Specifically calling: `getSelectedItem()`.

[How to use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

If you are only using Floats as options you can put the value in the combo box as Float objects so that you don't have to parse it on the way out.

Example:

```
    JComboBox<Float> box = new JComboBox<Float>();
    box.addItem(3f);
    box.addItem(4f);

    // something


    Float selected = box.getItemAt(box.getSelectedIndex());
```

Comment: it says object cannot be converted into string @jzd

Comment: Yes, getSelectedItem() returns an Object.